# Center the text in the Landscape position

Tags: html, css

When the user turns the phone, I would like it to be locked and a text message will be shown in the center of the screen

DEMO:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    html {
        /* Rotate the content container */
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform-origin: left top;
        /* Set content width to viewport height */
        width: 100vh;
        /* Set content height to viewport width */
        height: 100vw;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    .landscapeView {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999999;
        display: block;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    .mytext {
        font-size: 26px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #68D585;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="landscapeView">
    <span class="mytext">My text on middle screen</span>
</div>
```

Rotation lock works but I can't center the text vertically

Comment: Top and left won't do anything without [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Remove `float: left` as well

Comment: @MrT It didn't matter in this regard. I deleted it and nothing has changed. I updated code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the text in x axis, add the following code:

```css
.landscapeView{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

If you want to center the text in y axis, add the following code:

```css
.landscapeView{
   display; flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: He could also use `text-align:center` on `.landscapeView` for horizontal, even better